# Size max of an Android market app?

Tags: android

Is there a limit on the size of an android application in the market ?

I've an application with a lot of sound, so the apk size is more than 10 Mb...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-market-client-update.html) recent Android Developers Blog post, **50 MB** is the new limit. However, you should try to keep your app's size well below this limit.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better be bothered with your apk size. 10 Mb is too much for built-in memory, as not all the android devices let you install the application to sd card. Also, it is hard to download if 3g is used.

Please, consider decreasing size of your sounds by compressing it. Make sure you use all of the sounds and images, compress all you can, use some obfuscator tools to decrease the size of apk.

Answer (score 0):

"Currently the maximum file size limit for an app
upload to Android Market is approximately 25 MB." -from Google's Android site (www.android.com).

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2017, the official Android website specifies the following:

(1) The maximum size for an APK published on Google Play is **100 MB**.

(2) You can use up to **two APK Expansion Files**, each up to **2GB in size** (for each APK).

Here is the link to the official Android website about the latest MAX size (**as of January 2017**) : https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

If you click on that link, and scroll down to item (**6 - Confirm the App's Overall Size**), you will find the info about the MAX size.

=====

Therefore, your app should be fine as Android is now very generous about the MAX size).

However,  please be careful about using too much memory on mobile devices without properly releasing the memory after usage as that may cause your app to crash unexpectedly.   :-)