# Problem to build the apk file from eclipse

Tags: android

I am working on project which contains large number of data in assets folder, its around 1GB .When I'm going to make the apk file from eclipse to AndroidTools>Export Sign Package it's showing me ProjectName/bin/project.apk does not exist. When I remove some data from assets and make it around 200MB then it lets me to build the apk file.

So I have to find another alternative to deal with large data to parse from server, but in the iphone it support to store such large data so I wondered if there is any trick to deal with large data in android, locally.

If android doesn't support this size then please post your opinion, should google team consider this kind of problem (in other words its about security reason ??)

Comment: Host the data on a server and download it on first install.

Comment: Imagine the size of your apk file if you'll have 1Gb of data in your assets folder. It's a completely wrong approach. If you're having such amount of data, you should store it on a server and load it when your application starts on the first time. If that's not a secret, what kind of data it is? Will the app be published on Android Market? You should keep in mind that user may not want to give your application 1Gb of free memory.

Comment: You can't upload apps to the android market that are more then 50MB size:
[android market max size for an app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387609/size-max-of-an-android-market-app)

Comment: @ ALL : My project is not for the upload on the market its kind of solution so only use for few people . and the user the data is private so i cant let the user to download it from server and store in SD card ..so i have to go through this approach ..

Answer (score 0):

If your aim to use a large data through application then you have two way to do that .

1: Download from server and store in your SD card .

2: You said your project is not going to upload on android   market . if this would be a case then simply ask those user to save that data  in some specific folder on SD card and your app will use from there .

> There is no way to store 1GB data in APK file .